# Angular2 import issue when app.component.ts renamed to app.ts

Tags: typescript, angular

I was having a go at Angular2 with Typescript.

Following the 5 min QuickStart Tutorial when we create file `app.component.ts`, i tried renaming it to `app.ts`.

So to include this file i have to update the import statement in main.ts

Original statement: `import {AppComponent} from './app.component';`

Now if i change this to `import {AppComponent} from './app';` it doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong here ?

**Edit:** Error message logged in npm-debug.log

```
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ang2
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at makeError (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:264:12)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:242:14)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request._callback (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:172:14)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:199:22)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:185:7)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1036:10)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:963:12)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for ang2 { [Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ang2] pkgid: 'ang2', statusCode: 404, code: 'E404' }
20 verbose stack Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ang2
20 verbose stack     at makeError (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:264:12)
20 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:242:14)
20 verbose stack     at Request._callback (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:172:14)
20 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:199:22)
20 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
20 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:185:7)
20 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1036:10)
20 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
20 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
20 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manmeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:963:12)
```

**Edit 2**: Changing the import statement to `import {AppComponent} from './app.';` fixes the problem.

Why does this fix it ?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Some error message?

Comment: typescript compiler fails as it is unable to find the file

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: firstly make  sure what you want to ask as question, and try to put proper error message and your problem in your question..